# How to launch Google Earth plugin within Chrome

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I have the Google Earth plugin installed and it seems to work fine.

What I would like to do is open a KML file (exported from MyTracks on Android) in it.

But, I can find no option to open the KML file, or launch the GE plugin.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch the plugin take a look at the '[Using the Google Earth Api](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index#using_the_google_earth_api)' section in the [developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index).

For loading KML files, take a look at the following documentation https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml

It give examples of how to [fetchKml and parseKml](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml#fetchkml_and_parsekml) as well as linking to a [working example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/earth/documentation/samples/fetchkml_example).

```
var href = 'http://code.google.com/'
               + 'apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example.kml';

google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function(kmlObject) {
  if (kmlObject) {
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
  }
});
```

You can also use a `KmlNetworkLink` to [load the data](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml#kmlnetworklink) again the document links to a [working example](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/samples/kmlnetworklink_example) of this.

```
var link = ge.createLink('');
var href = 'http://code.google.com/'
           + 'apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example.kml'
link.setHref(href);

var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('');
networkLink.set(link, true, true); // Sets the link, refreshVisibility, and flyToView

ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
```